# Are tangent spaces at different points disjoint according to this definition?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces, tangent-bundle

In [this](https://youtu.be/XZcKSoI17r0?t=5320) lecture by Prof. F. P. Schuller (I've included the correct time stamp) it is claimed that two tangent spaces at different points are disjoint, i.e. $T_pM\cap T_qM =\emptyset$ for $p,q\in M$ and $p\neq q$. In [this](https://youtu.be/UPGoXBfm6Js?t=1026) lecture, the tangent space at a point $p\in M$ was defined as

$$ T_pM:=\{X_{\gamma,p}|\gamma \,\mathrm{is\, a\, smooth\, curve\, through\,p}\} \quad,$$

i.e. the collection of the [directional derivatives](https://youtu.be/UPGoXBfm6Js?t=447) along all (smooth) curves through $p$:

$$X_{\gamma,p}:\mathcal C^\infty(M) \longrightarrow \mathbb R$$
with

$$ X_{\gamma,p} : f\mapsto \left(f\circ\gamma\right)^\prime(0) \quad ,$$

where $\gamma(0)=p$.

I don't understand the aforementioned claim. If we take two constants curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ going through $p$ and $q$, respectively then we have two directional derivative operators at these points which are both the $0$-map, i.e. $X_{\gamma_1,p} = X_{\gamma_2,p}=0$, where $0: f\mapsto 0 $ by a mild abuse of notation; so I think that since both are equal as operators, both are elements in each tangent space. What do I miss here? Further, is there any non-trivial "overlap" between two tangent spaces at different points?

PS: I know there are some other question regarding the disjointness of tangent spaces at different points here on math stackexchange; however, I could not find the definition used here.

Comment: To put emphasis on the disjointness, the author should have consider the space of germs of smooth functions at $p$ instead of all smooth functions. But it is just a technical point

Comment: @Didier Thanks for your comment. I don't have any clue what "germs" are. If you don't mind and have time, I'd really appreciate if you could elaborate. Note that I am not a mathematician.

Comment: Heuristically, a germ of a function at a point $x$ is an equivalent class of functions that are equal in a neighbourhood of $x$. In some sense, it get rid of what can be the function away from $x$ and just catch the local behaviour around that point. For instance, a function that vanishes in a neighbourhood of $x$ but is not identically zero will be considered as the same germ as the null function. Coming back to your question, a tangent vector at $x$ acts on the set of germs of functions at $x$, which is not the same set as the germs of functions at $y\neq x$, and tangent spaces are disjoint.

Comment: @Didier Ah okay, I think I get the rough idea. By doing so, we construct only operators on $\mathcal C_p^\infty (M)$ as elements of the tangent space at this point? And then, is it correct to say that we have for each $p$, for example a different $0$ operator - one on each $\mathcal C_p^\infty (M)$? And the difference comes from the different domain? Is that (roughly) correct?

Comment: This is exactly that!

Comment: @Didier Thank you very much! If you want to put this as an answer, I could accept it. If you don't mind, however, I have a small question regarding your first comment, which said that this is a technical point only: Is there any "practical" advantage in defining the tangent space in terms of germs rather as done in the lectures? In other words, is there an advantage to have disjoint tangent spaces? Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: In the video, the lecturer defines the tangent bundle to be the [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union) of tangent spaces. In this case, it does not matter if in the definition, tangent spaces are disjoint or not, as long as the tangent bundle is defined that way. This is why we can talk about **the** projection of a tangent vector onto $M$ (the lecturer seems to put an emphasis on that around 1:31:00 in the video you linked). Regarding putting an answer, feel free to post what you learnt and understood! I don't really have time to do so right now

Comment: Note the condition for the tangent space at $p$ that $\gamma(0)=p$. You can have a curve that passes through $p$ and $q$, but the curve won't have $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma(0)=q$ for different points $p,q$!

Comment: @JoshuaTilley Thanks for your comment. Could you elaborate how this exactly relates to my question, i.e. does this imply, somehow that the tangent spaces are mutually disjoint (or not)? In my understanding, the very same operator can arise from different curves at different points and thus it would be an element in two (or more) tangent spaces, as I've tried to show with the $0$-operator. However, I don't know if there are other non-trivial constructions like this and hence the last question in the post.

Comment: Actually, I mistook your argument. You correctly show that the tangent spaces defined in this way are not disjoint as subsets of the dual space $C^\infty(M)^\ast$. However, they are disjoint in $TM$, either by using germs as Didier suggests, or defining $TM$ by a *disjoint* union.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the very helpful comments of @Didier, I think I understand the issue. The following answer just summarizes the comments. If someone still wants to expand and give a more elaborated explanation, please do so - I'd highly appreciate it.

Indeed, with the definition of $T_pM$ as in the lecture the tangent spaces are not disjoint, cf. my counter example in the question. For our purposes, the construction of the tangent bundle $TM:=\dot \bigcup_{p\in M}\,T_pM$, however, this causes no problems since we consider the *disjoint* union of the tangent spaces.

Yet, we can construct tangent spaces which are mutually disjoint. To do so, we have to build the tangent spaces at a point $p\in M$ from operators defined on the germs of (smooth) functions at $p$. By doing so, the tangent spaces at different points are mutually disjoint because their elements are defined on different domains.